# Decode Body from Attachment Object

Tags: attachment

I'm trying to decode the body field of the Attachment Object in salesforce doing this:

```
String bodyContent = documento.Body.toString();
Blob bodyDocumentoBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(bodyContent);
bodyDocumento = bodyDocumentoBlob.toString();
```

When I try it in the application I get this error:

> System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Could anybody help me?

Comment: What file type this is?

Answer (score 0):

Blob only supports files with UTF-8 format.So Please check whether your file is UTF-8 encoded.You will get this error when there are special characters in the file